# Spring Boot static resources are in my built jar but not in jar deployed to Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, static-files

I wonder if the title of this post shouldn't be "I'm ignorant." This is obviously a common problem and I've read multiple threads on it but somewhere I'm missing knowledge or... something.

- /questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content
- /questions/54735747/spring-boot-not-serving-static-files-from-inside-jar
- /questions/63061943/how-to-load-static-files-with-spring-boot-inside-a-docker-container-hosted-on-aw

I've confirmed that my problem is that the static resources aren't making it to Docker. Using CLI, I can unzip the jar there and see that no html, js, or css files are there.

However, I've confirmed that the jar I'm using (I think I'm using it, anyway. I don't know how it couldn't be.) does have them in it. It's as if they're getting deliberately extracted and excluded somehow.

Here's my application.properties:

```
#FOR LOCAL
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/library

#FOR DOCKER
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresqldb:5432/library

spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

#The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

#Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

#This enables app to serve the static content. Not sure why I need it, but it makes it work locally.
server.contextPath=/
```

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/microservice1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} bookws.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/bookws.jar"]
```

And here's my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  app:
    container_name: bookws
    image: bookws
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgresqldb
  postgresqldb:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=library
```

Here's my main java file:

```
//package and imports excluded for brevity

@SpringBootApplication
public class Microservice1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Microservice1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

My static resources are stored in src/main/resources/static

```
static/index.html
static/js/book-crud.js
static/js/jquery-3.5.0.min.js
static/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js
static/css/main.css
static/img/ (some .pngs and some .jpgs)
```

EDIT: Adding my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.familam.learning'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
//  annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Thanks in advance for any insights!! If I need to add any further info, I'm happy to. What is the probably simple thing I'm missing?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm just ignorant.  Why is it that you are talking about two different jar files?  Why can't you deploy the jar file you have that you know has all of the right stuff in it to Docker?  What makes the Docker version different, and why?

Comment: I would consider looking at Jib or Spring's Docker support rather than maintaining your own Dockerfile with the JAR version hard-coded. Otherwise, please show your Maven/Gradle build scripts

Comment: @Steve I guess your question is exactly what I'm wondering--why are they different. I *think* I am deploying it right into Docker. I'm baffled as to why, when I unzip them separately (using CLI to access the one in Docker), they're different.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Gradle script added, thank you! I'll start researching Jib and Spring's Docker support now. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, it seems nothing I change is making a difference. Is it possible that it's re-using the same image every time, rather than using the re-built jar and creating a new image?

Perhaps I'm missing a command. All I ever type in is: 'docker-compose up', ctr-c to kill it, then 'docker-compose down' to remove it. Am I supposed to do something else in there to create a new image?

Comment: Oh my. See, I knew it was something dumb. I'm unfamiliar with docker-compose and picked that part up from a tutorial.

I thought 'docker-compose up' automatically built a new image and launched it. All I needed to do was add the 'docker-compose build' step. Facepalm.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not with my configuration, but with my ignorance of how docker-compose works. The docker-compose command 'up' does not re-build the docker image. You need to run the 'docker-compose build' command first. That was all I was lacking.

Comment: Or, you can do both in one go: `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: But in practice, it is probably better to do `docker-compose build && docker-compose up --force-recreate`, so that the image is rebuilt while the previous version is still running… to reduce the offline time as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the tips!